# Chaining together javascript requests in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to chain together multiple requests with just a different body request, specifically different block_num_ids. Using the [request npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

```
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'some_url',
  headers: {accept: 'application/json', 'content-type': 'application/json'},
  body: '{"block_num_or_id":"different_block_numbers"}'
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

What's the best way to go about doing this? I've considered using a generator and pushing the returned JSON into an array and then iterating over those in react with map to display the values. Is this the most developer friendly way of doing this? For reference I'm considering using a generator like this...

```
function* foo(index) {
  while (index < 10) {
    yield index++;
  }
}

const iterator = foo(1);

console.log(iterator.next().value);
```

Comment: Sounds like you need promises? Promise.all()

Comment: If this is in redux you should really look into [redux sagas](https://redux-saga.js.org/) I use them at work and the `yield` statement is a life saver. Essentially you'd write `yield call ...request...` and you can write the next asynchronous one right under it in the same format

Comment: I would start looking at https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/ (and https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable if you use redux)